# SQL Server Query Strange Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL Server query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MIN(P), 999) AS FLD
FROM (SELECT '0' AS P) AS T
WHERE (1 > 4)
```

How come the output of this query is '*' ?

Please explain

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ISNULL` uses the datatype of the first argument.

This is `varchar(1)` as that is the datatype of the literal `'0'`

`999` would be truncated so SQL Server shows '*'

Comment: What about 1>4 ? SELECT ISNULL(MIN('0'), 999) WHERE 1>4 gives '*' but SELECT ISNULL('0', 999) WHERE 1>4 gives an empty result!

Comment: @Scorpi0 Aggregates without a `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` will always return exactly one row. This is a scalar aggregate (as opposed to a vector aggregate). A scalar aggregate `MIN` on an empty result set will return `NULL`

Comment: I'm still confused. SELECT ISNULL(MIN('0'), 999) output '0'. the fact that there is no WHERE clause changed the nature of the MIN operator ?

Comment: @Scorpi0 - When you do `SELECT` without a `FROM` in SQL Server it is as though you were selecting from a single row table (similar to `FROM DUAL` in other RDBMSs). So `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns `1` for example. If you try `SELECT ISNULL(MIN('0'), 999) WHERE 1 = 0` then this is an aggregate on an empty result set again and the `MIN` returns `NULL`

Comment: @Scorpi0 I think the cach here is `varchar(1)` as @MartinSmith suggested .Try this . `Select ISNULL(convert(varchar(1),null),999)`

Comment: Many thanks @MartinSmith yes, it is very similar to: declare ATp varchar(1)
SELECT ISNULL(ATp, 999) AS FLD
 and the output will be * because 999 to varchar(1) will be *, and for Sorpi0 it is SELECT ISNULL(NULL, 999) because MIN(foo) return null where condition is false. Many thanks for your help.